# SQL : Running Total for identical transactions Without Using ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate a running total of *"cab fare earned by a driver on a particular day"*. Originally tested on Netezza and now trying to code on spark-sql.

However if for two rows with structure as ((driver,day) --> fare) if 'fare' value is **identical** then running_total column always showing the **final sum** ! In case all the fares **are distinct** , it is being calculated perfectly. Is there any way to achieve this ( in ANSI SQL or Spark dataframe) without using rowsBetween(start,end) ?

Sample Data :

```
    driver_id<<<<>>>>date_id  <<<<>>>>fare
    10001           2017-07-27        500
    10001           2017-07-27        500
    10001           2017-07-30        500
    10001           2017-07-30        1500
```

SQL Query I fired to calculate running total

```
    select driver_id, date_id, fare , 
    sum(fare)
    over(partition by date_id,driver_id 
    order by date_id,fare ) 
    as run_tot_fare
    from trip_info
    order by 2
```

Result :

```
  driver_id <<<<>>>> date_id <<<<>>>> fare <<<<>>>> run_tot_fare
  10001              2017-07-27       500           1000 --**Showing Final Total expecting 500**
  10001              2017-07-27       500           1000
  10001              2017-07-30       500           500 --**No problem here**
  10001              2017-07-30       1500          2000
```

If anybody can kindly let me know,what  I am doing wrong and if it is achievable without using Rows Unbounded Precedings/rowsBetween(b,e), then I highly appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use `range between unbounded preceding and current row`?

Comment: @gordon linoff 1. ideally I would like to avoid that as spark-job is getting almost 5x slow when I tried. Also please show me how to do it either in sql/spark-sql Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional solution in SQL is to use `range` instead of `rows`:

```
select driver_id, date_id, fare , 
       sum(fare) over (partition by date_id, driver_id 
                       order by date_id, fare
                       range between unbounded preceding and current rows
                      ) as run_tot_fare
from trip_info
order by 2;
```

Absent that, two levels of window functions or an aggregation and join:

```
select driver_id, date_id, fare,
       max(run_tot_fare_temp) over (partition by date_id, driver_id ) as run_tot_fare
from (select driver_id, date_id, fare , 
             sum(fare) over (partition by date_id, driver_id 
                             order by date_id, fare
                            ) as run_tot_fare_temp
      from trip_info ti
  ) ti
order by 2;
```

(The `max()` assumes the fares are never negative.)

Comment: Why did you use `order by 2` instead of date_id?

Comment: @Hogan . . . Because I copied the OP's query and the outer `order by` is not germane to the question.

Comment: ah of course I didn't look at all of the OP's code.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  --- I tried the max() solution, it does not work at all , also I believe you tried to say max(run_tot_fare_temp) over(<partition by> date_id,driver_id). Anyway, to avoid using rowsBetween(), I will filter my input table(dataframe) for records having duplicate combo in same driver/date_id group and having distinct value and then run one with rowsBetween() and one without... i hope it will not cause spark to try persist all the previous records .